# Application of Hahn Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $P=\{p\vert\partial D: p=$an analytic polynomial} and consider P as a manifold in $C(\partial D)$. Show that if $\mu$ is a real-valued measure on $\partial D$ such that $\int p d\mu=0$ for every p in P, then $\mu=0$. Give an example of a complex-valued measure $\mu$ such that $\mu\neq0$ but $\int p d\mu=0$ for every p in P.

P is subspace of $C(\partial D)$. Let $\Lambda : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\Lambda(f)=f(a)$. Then, By Maximal Module's theorem and Hahn-Banach Theorem, we can conclude $p(a)=0$ for every p in P. But, I don't know how to conclude $\mu=0$. How to prove that?

Answer (score 1):

Is $P$ dense in $\mathcal{C}(\partial D)$?  If so, then Hahn-Banach extends 
"$0$ on $P$" to "$0$ on $\mathcal{C}(\partial D)$" (since the extension must have the same norm).

If you don't know $P$ is dense in $\mathcal{C}(\partial D)$, I'd try Stone-Weierstraß.

Comment: I know that If X is a normed space and M is a linear manifold in X, then M is dense in X if and only if only bounded linear functional on X that annihilates M is the zero functional.

Comment: How to know $\mu=0$?